# Android Display ArrayList<String[]> in ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, arraylist

I am currently working on an application for my company.
The App is working with a sqlite Database, stored on the external Storage.

Now I want to Display all Table Names of the Database in a ListView

The Part where I get the Table Names looks like this:

```js
    public ArrayList < String[] > getDBTables() {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

      Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);
      ArrayList < String[] > result = new ArrayList < String[] > ();
      int i = 0;
      result.add(c.getColumnNames());
      for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        String[] temp = new String[c.getColumnCount()];
        for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
          temp[i] = c.getString(i);
          System.out.println("TABLE - " + temp[i]);

        }
        result.add(temp);

      }

      return result;
    }
```

And it is working just fine.
But now I have to display it in a ListView and there the problems began.

I tried it like that:

```js
      dbTablesView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


 ArrayList<String[]> tables;
 tables=datasource.getDBTables();

 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tables );

 dbTablesView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

But it tells me, that I cant use java.util.ArrayList to create the Adapter.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: do not use `ArrayAdapter`, use `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead

Comment: @airflyer13 the problem looks to me is you have not properly initialized ArrayList

Comment: you should use custom arrayAdapter.

Comment: You are defining the Layout Resource Id containing a TextView in the `ArrayAdapter` constructor - how can 1 TextView show a String Array - passed object: `List<String[]>` ? I haven't tried this myself, but I wouldn't think that is possible - You can always create a custom adapter that dynamically creates TextViews the length of your String[] for each List position.

Comment: Right you should use ArrayList<String> instead